# Populate Column Separate Spreadsheet with Data from Index created from tabs in workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an index created from the worksheet names. I would like to populate a cell in a separate spreadsheet where a column A has numbers 1-500 and if the criteria (Type) is true then add to next available cell next to a number. If the criteria (Type) is not met then it would skip to the next item. It would only post the data from the index in the other spreadsheet if the criteria (Type) is met.

```
Index
Worksheet Name  Desc    Type
Test1           one       A
Test2           two       A
Test3           three     A
Test4           four      B
Test5           five      A
Test6           six       A
Test7           seven     C
Test8           eight     A
Test9           nine      A
Test10          ten       A
Test11          eleven    A
Test12          twelve    B
Test13          thirteen  A
Test14          fourteen  C
Test15          fifteen   A
```

Seperate spreadsheet

```
Num  WS
1   Test1

2   Test2

3   Test3

4   Test5

5   Test6

6   Test8

7   Test9

8   Test10

9   Test11

10  Test13
```

Comment: Is this possible with an excel formula?

Comment: I used this formula and it works perfectly.  Thank you for your time  =IF(Worksheet!E8="A",MAX($A$2:A3)+1,"")